# How to prevent HTML Form buttons link to same location

Tags: html, forms, post, get

I'm wanting to create a 'Sort' section on my website where I can sort products by price ASC or DESC, I've fully coded this up with PHP, and it works fine without the search bar code on my site, my problem is that when I press the button I've named 'Sort', it some how gets confused with my previous HTML form which is used for my search bar..

So it re-directs straight to 'Search.php', instead of just adding '?Sort=PriceAsc' onto the current search bar

Here is my HTML code for the forms:

```
<!-- Search form -->

<div ID = "Search">
<form action="Search.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="SearchQuery" size="60" style="border:3px solid #000" placeholder = "Search"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" /> 
</div>


<!-- Sort form -->

<div ID = "Sort">
<form method="get" name="Sort">
<select name="Sort">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value='PriceAsc'>Price: Low - High</option>
<option value='PriceDesc'>Price: High - Low</option> </select>
<input type="submit" value="Sort"/>
</form>
</div>
```

I'm really unsure how to fix this, I've tried so many things, such as adding + changing form actions etc

Also one last thing to point out is that I can add '?Sort=PriceAsc' or '?Sort=PriceDesc' onto the url bar and it works fine, but I really want my form button to be able to carry out this task.

Comment: You'll need to add names to your forms in order to separate functionality.

Comment: Oh and close your form tag on your first form!

Comment: Wow I'm so stupid, Silly mistake that is, I've been working on it for days, so I guess it was difficult for me to spot that simple error, Thanks a lot + sorry for wasting everyone's time with such an easy question

Comment: Add your fix as an answer and mark it as such. Don't worry sometimes it just needs more eyes.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that, how do I mark your comment as the solution?

Comment: I've added it as an answer :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing form tag (see blow)

```
<!-- Search form -->

<div ID = "Search">
<form action="Search.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="SearchQuery" size="60" style="border:3px solid #000" placeholder = "Search"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" /> 
</form>
</div>


<!-- Sort form -->

<div ID = "Sort">
<form method="get" name="Sort">
<select name="Sort">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value='PriceAsc'>Price: Low - High</option>
<option value='PriceDesc'>Price: High - Low</option> </select>
<input type="submit" value="Sort"/>
</form>
</div>
```

I'd recommend that you name the forms too.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah i'll do that too, I'll mark as solution once it lets me